# SortedProperties not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save a .properties file with entries sorted alphabetically using this class:
[SortedProperties](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0614.html)

Like this:

```
File file = new File(fullPathToCfgFile);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
getProperties().store(os, null);
os.close();

private static SortedProperties getProperties() {
    SortedProperties properties = new SortedProperties();
    Field[] fields = Settings.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        String fieldName = fields[i].getName();
        if (fieldName.startsWith("_")) {
            try {
                properties.put(fieldName, "" + fields[i].get(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return properties;
}
```

The problem is keys() from SortedProperties is never called, so the saved file is not sorted.

Comment: Are you sure it is due to not calling keys() method. I don't think calling .keys() is necessary. In [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/SortPropertieswhensaving.htm) keys method is not called and properties are saved in sorting manner.

Comment: I tested that code and it's still not sorting. Now I'm thinking maybe this doesn't work on Android (I'm making an app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and `keys()` is definitely invoked by `store()`.

I don't know what issues you are encountering, but it doesn't look to be in `SortedProperties`.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work on Android. On Windows it sorts fine, but on an Android phone it doesn't.

Comment: That is probably because the Andriod implementation of Properties differs from the one in Java's standard library.